# How can I check if a string equals an array entry in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to verify if the typed game title exists on an array, the response from ajax brings all the game titles inside the database.

So if the user types a game that exists, an message should be displayed.

Here's what I've tried:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function gameTitleValidation(str) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/getAjaxData',
        success: function (data) {
            if ($.inArray(str, $.each(data.game_titles))){
                alert("Game exists");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="form-group form-group-game">
   <label>Game title:</label><br>
   <input type="text" name="game_title" onkeyup="gameTitleValidation(this.value)"required>
</div>
```

It never enters the condition, what is it that I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't call `$.each` there. You should just pass the array. `each` is for calling a callback for each array element.

Comment: @trincot If I do that, the alert gets displayed everytime I press a key

Comment: first of all `data.game_titles` is a json string , you need to parse it .. `JSON.parse(data.game_titles)`, now you have an array to compare with

Comment: even though this comparison must be in the back-end and return true or false to ur front-end

Comment: @PsyLogic Hello, I've done as instructed, however it returns an error: backend-games:128 Uncaught ReferenceError: gameTitleValidation is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onkeyup (backend-games:128),

Your suggestion regarding backend validation was to send the input data through a post and validate it true or false there?

Comment: *"If I do that, the alert gets displayed every time I press a key"*: so you agree it answers your question ("it never enters the condition"). If you have another question now, you should ask about *that*. Make sure to provide a sample value for `data.game_titles` (in JavaScript notation), and what you want the desired effect to be for that example and a specific series of keys.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have few options here.

1. If you know that what is returned by the backend is an array:

- `data.game_titles.some(title => title === str)`
- `$.inArray(str, data.game_titles) >= 0` as the second argument in `$.inArray` should be array an itself

2. If what is returned by the backed is a string (for exanple coma separated values):

- `data.game_titles.indexOf(str) >= 0`